# How to build a query across parent and child object fields in Oracle CRM On Demand?

Tags: oracle, crm, ondemand

As a part of an Integration Requirement, I need to query Opportunity records that have been Modified after a specific date and time?

Now, Opportunity has a child object called ProductRevenue with a one to many relationship. Is there anyway I can construct a querypage that will fetch records whose Opportunity fields 'OR' its child ProductRevenue's fields have been modified after a specific date and time?

I have tried using the SearchSpec argument, but it does not let me query across child object fields.

For eg:

`ObjOpptyQueryPageInput.ListOfOpportunity.Opportunity.searchspec = "([ModifiedDate] > '01/01/2013 00:00:00') OR ([ProductRevenueData.ModifiedDate] >= '01/01/2013 00:00:00')";`

[This above code written in C# thew me an error saying - The object Opportunity does not have an integration component called - ProductRevenueData.ModifiedDate.]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for the answer myself, and here is my understanding although not a solution.

In Web Services 2.0, Oracle says "all parent records matching the parent criteria and only children matching the child criteria are returned."

You actually can define "searchspec" on the parent AND the child, and it does work in the way that Oracle defined. However it is probably not the behavior you are looking for. When you do this what happens is you get ALL parents that match the parent.searchspec regardless of whether its child matches the child.searchspec. However those parents will only have the child(ren) that match your child.searchspec in the query result. So if all you wanted was "parents that have these children" or "these children" you are out of luck. Because what you get is "many parents and some of their children."

So even when you are post-processing with two queries you will have to spend some time. :(

By the way your two separate queries will have to look something like this:

query 1.
 `ObjOpptyQueryPageInput.ListOfOpportunity.Opportunity.searchspec = "([ModifiedDate] > '01/01/2013 00:00:00')";`

query 2.        `ObjOpptyQueryPageInput.ListOfOpportunity.Opportunity.ListOfProductRevenue.ProductRevenue.searchspec = "([ModifiedDate] >= '01/01/2013 00:00:00')";`

Then post-process query 2 to take out all parents who have no children.
Then union that with the results from query 1.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, you will not be able to do this using their V2.0 api (i.e. searchspec). You can perform this using V1.0 api BUT this will return all parent records matching your criteria plus all related ProductRevenue records whether they meet the criteria or not.  I do something similar and then post process the data against an xpath predicate filter. The only other option, I think, is 2 separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and i tried many ways to resolve the problem, but for now you should deal with the result returned: you can use `DOM`, `XPath` or `regular expressions` to extract the information you want for the returned result.

In my case i used XPath because it's very fast and more easier. This is a link to the question i have posted with the correct answer :
[Xpath solution for the parent-child query result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33871368/get-elements-by-attribute-value)

I hope this will fix the problem.