# get elements by attribute value

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, xpath

I am sending a request via `webservices` in `Javascript` and the response i am receiving is like this:

```
<ListOfBook>
<Book>
    <Id>ACIA-11QWTKX</Id>
    <ListOfBookUser recordcount="0" lastpage="true">
    </ListOfBookUser>
</Book>
<Book>
    <Id>ACIA-ANC0CC</Id>
    <ListOfBookUser recordcount="1" lastpage="true">
        <BookUser>
            <BookId>ACIA-ANC0CC</BookId>
            <BookName>TKSP_GLOBAL</BookName>
        </BookUser>
        </ListOfBookUser>
</Book>                             
<Book>
    <Id>ACIA-ANC0CF</Id>
    <ListOfBookUser recordcount="0" lastpage="true">
    </ListOfBookUser>
</Book>
<Book>
    <Id>ACIA-EUMCH5</Id>
    <ListOfBookUser recordcount="1" lastpage="true">
        <BookUser>
            <BookId>ACIA-EUMCH5</BookId>
            <BookName>TKSP_MADRID_CENTRO_SUR</BookName>
        </BookUser>
    </ListOfBookUser>
</Book>
```

As you can see there are some elements of `<Book>` that have a child `<BookUser>` and there are other elements that doesn't have this child.

I need a way to extract elements of `<Book>` that have the `<BookUser>` child with `regular expressions`, `DOM` or `Xpath`. Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Xpath for xml for sure

Comment: There are some `Book` elements with a `BookUser` grand child, I don't see any having a child of that name. XPath would `//Book[ListOfBookUser/BookUser]`.

Comment: But how to use Xpath in Javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPath with an expression like `//Book[ListOfBookUser/BookUser]`:

```js
var xmlMarkup = `<ListOfBook>
<Book>
    <Id>ACIA-11QWTKX</Id>
    <ListOfBookUser recordcount="0" lastpage="true">
    </ListOfBookUser>
</Book>
<Book>
    <Id>ACIA-ANC0CC</Id>
    <ListOfBookUser recordcount="1" lastpage="true">
        <BookUser>
            <BookId>ACIA-ANC0CC</BookId>
            <BookName>TKSP_GLOBAL</BookName>
        </BookUser>
        </ListOfBookUser>
</Book>                             
<Book>
    <Id>ACIA-ANC0CF</Id>
    <ListOfBookUser recordcount="0" lastpage="true">
    </ListOfBookUser>
</Book>
<Book>
    <Id>ACIA-EUMCH5</Id>
    <ListOfBookUser recordcount="1" lastpage="true">
        <BookUser>
            <BookId>ACIA-EUMCH5</BookId>
            <BookName>TKSP_MADRID_CENTRO_SUR</BookName>
        </BookUser>
    </ListOfBookUser>
</Book>
</ListOfBook>`;

var xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlMarkup, 'application/xml');
var bookSnapshot = xmlDoc.evaluate('//Book[ListOfBookUser/BookUser]', xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
for (var i = 0, l = bookSnapshot.snapshotLength; i < l; i++) {
  var book = bookSnapshot.snapshotItem(i);
  var id = xmlDoc.evaluate('Id', book, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  if (id != null) {
    console.log(id.textContent);
  }
}
```

For brevity of the sample, I have used the multi-line string literal delimiters `` only implemented in actual browsers, but the XPath API is supported in DOM implementations in Mozilla, Chrome, Safari and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xpath` you can do this to extract all `Book` elements that have `BookUser` descendants (you need to look for descendants not for children, since your `BookUsers` are contained inside `ListOfBookUser` tags:

```
//Book[descendant::BookUser]
```

or

```
//Book[.//BookUser]
```

or (as @MartinHonnen showed in the comments):

```
//Book[ListOfBookUser/BookUser]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to use `Xpath` in `Javascript` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see:

[MDN]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

[W3Schools] : http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_examples.asp

.evaluate function is usefull.